# Selenium program returning NoSuchElementException no matter what element query type I use?

Tags: java, html, selenium, google-chrome, web-scraping

I have a stock data site that I am trying to use Selenium to parse data from. I feel like I'm really close, but something in my code is causing the program to return a NoSuchElementException. I can do a JS query of the page (https://www.cnbc.com/quotes/?symbol=.DJI) using my desired element from the Chrome developer console as follows:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("last original ng-binding")
```

However, doing a similar query in my Java-based Selenium program to find the element by class name returns this exception. Why that be when I'm using the same class name as the JS query? I've tried doing queries by xpath and css as well with a similar error. Here's my code I have:

```
//Built in Java 1.7 due to Selenium compatabilities

//Import packages
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.By.ByClassName;
import org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException;
import org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Tester {

//Instantiate common variables
WebDriver driver;
String url;
Scanner input;
boolean error;
int uses = 0;

public void invokeBrowser() {
    try {
        //Point Selenium to Chrome Driver file
         File file = new File("C:\\Users\\zrr81\\eclipse-workspace\\WebScraper\\Selenium\\chromedriver.exe");
         System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());

         //Initialize Chrome driver and perform maintenance functions
         driver = new ChromeDriver();
         driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
         uses ++;

         //Execute parseData code
         parseData();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

//Try to connect, include catch for typos/errors
public void parseData() {
     try {
         input = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.println("Enter the url you would like to connect to: ");
         String url = input.nextLine();
         driver.get(url);
         elementLocator();

     }
     //Specific catch for an invalid site (e.g. a dead link)
     catch(InvalidArgumentException e) {
         System.out.println("He's dead Jim! :/");
     }
     //Catch for all other exceptions
     catch(Exception ex) {
         System.out.println("Check your syntax partner!");
     }
}

public void elementLocator() {
    try {
        //driver.findElement(By.linkText("DJIA</a>")).click();
        String stock = driver.findElement(By.className("last original ng-binding")).toString();
        System.out.println(stock);
    //Catch specific exception for html element not found
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        System.out.println("Selected element not found");
        error = true;
    //General exception catch
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        if (error==true) {
            closeBrowser();
        }
    }
}

public void closeBrowser() {
    //If only 1 window is open, close the window
    if(uses == 1) {
        driver.close();
    }
    //Otherwise, close the whole browser
    else {
        driver.quit();
    }
}

//Invoke methods
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Tester myObj = new Tester();
    myObj.invokeBrowser();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NoSuchElement exception occurs when element is not present on the web page for procession during Runtime. Also , your findElement is wrong in your code. Please refer below code to print `23,433.57` from your webpage.

```
WebElement TxtBoxContent = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("td > .last:nth-child(1)"));
System.out.println("Text " +TxtBoxContent.getText());
```

[image]

Comment: One extra parenthesis, but otherwise exactly what I needed! Thank you so much, I've spent HOURS trying to get this formatting correct!!

Comment: would you kind enough to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) answer and hit upvote button  from your end.

Comment: You were just a bit ahead of me haha. Just did!